# Variance Homogeneity for a mixed model

Tags: r, mixed-model, variance

I have run the model:

```
model2 <- lmer(tas ~ station + (1 | date), data = all5)
```

where `station` is a categorical variable with 4 levels.
I want to check for variance homogeneity.
I find the residuals from `lmerresid <- resid(model2)`.
If I run the levene test:
`leveneTest(lmerresid ~ all5$station)` I get p = 0.6572 so it implies homogeneity of variances.
If I make the boxplots it implies homogeneity of variances:

```
boxplot(lmerresid ~ all5$station)
```

[image]
But if I plot residuals vs fited then there is sth wrong:
#Plot vs factors

```
par(mfrow = c(1,1))
plot(lmerresid ~ fitted(model2))
```

[image]

Are the variances homogeneous?

Comment: Your question is missing the word "enough". I would say your model is probably missing predictors but it might be good enough. You could [derive robust standard errors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70268157/1412059) to be on the safe side.